# What happens when you pass the same account as writable twice in a single ix but fail to sync the data manually?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-lang

I'm required to use conditional logic in my ix where two mutable references to accounts could be be pointing to the same account. What happens when I don't sync them at the end?

Answer (score 2):

You can use both accounts' values independently within your program but once the program is executed the final data that is saved on the blockchain is the data stored inside the last account passed to the instruction.

For example for this accounts structure, if `accountFoo` and `accountBar` point to the same account:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct ChangeAccountsData<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub accountFoo: Account<'info, MyAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub accountBar: Account<'info, MyAccount>,
    ...
}
```

After the ix is executed, the value in `accountBar` is the one that is saved on the blockchain.

If you switch the accounts' order like this:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct ChangeAccountsData<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub accountBar: Account<'info, MyAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub accountFoo: Account<'info, MyAccount>,
    ...
}
```

The value in `accountFoo` is the one that will be saved on the blockchain.